# How do you call a timepicker from a preference activity?

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, timepicker

Can you tell me how to call a time picker from a preference activity?

Can you show the needed manifest.xml, layout.xml and code inside the preference activity and any other needed files to call the time picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a TimePicker to a standar Activity, add the TimePicker widget to your layout like this:

```
<TimePicker android:id="@+id/timePicker" android:layout_below="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Next, have your activity implement OnTimeChangedListener.  Then you'll need to add the following method to your activity:

```
private void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time here
}
```

To call a TimePicker from a PreferenceActivity, you may want to consider popping up a dialog to handle the selection of time from the user.   Have a look at this class which shows an implementation of doing so:
http://code.google.com/p/onlinemanager/source/browse/trunk/WebViewer/src/fr/webviewer/activity/PreferenceActivity.java?r=76

Comment: Hi SBerg413, Thanks for the helpful code samples. I will use it. Truly, Emad